# Cypress baseUrl configuation

Tags: cypress

Can I ask how to maybe overcome that i setup one baseURL for my cypress but in i want to run tests for different URL in diffrent folders. But setting baseURL limits me only for that particular URL testing

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add multiple URLs in your **cypress.json** file like:

```
{
   "appurl1":"www.website1.com",
   "appurl2":"www.website2.com"
}
```

and then access those in the tests like:

```
Cypress.config('appUrl1')
Cypress.config('appUrl2')
```

Check out the cypress docs on [Cypress.config](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/config.html#Syntax).

Comment: but baseURL is need?

Comment: @Exc Hey can you post your tests and elaborate a bit on what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: what i want ot achive is that if i haed code baseURL so i can only run testes on this URL so my testes are focused only on that but your solution makes sense