# How to test two systems with different base URLs in a single test suite?

Tags: cypress

I'm working on a project that has multiple systems. (ex: admin portal, client portal, etc.) and there are different environments in each system (ex: dev env, QA env, etc.) There is a separate QA repository for e2e testing and I need to test different systems with different URLs in a single test suite.

This question [Cypress baseUrl configuation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63285829/cypress-baseurl-configuation) suggests a method of using multiple params in `cypress.json` to represent the different systems URLs and to use a `Cypress.config()` to refer to the correct URL. However, that method does not make use of the `baseURL` property of Cypress.

Is there any in-built capability in Cypress to support the testing of multiple systems in a single test suite? (for example, switch the `baseURL` from within test code or something of that sort)

Answer (score 3):

I guess you want to use `Cypress.config('baseUrl', <value>)` to set the baseUrl in a `beforeEach()`.

You will need to choose how to indicate the system you are testing, perhaps different scripts to start with an environment variable

```
cypress open --env system=admin,environ=qa
```

then in the test

```js
const baseUrls = {
  'admin-qa': 'http:/example.com'
  ...
}

beforeEach(()=> {
  const baseUrl = baseUrls[`${Cypress.env('system')-${Cypress.env('qa')}`];
  Cypress.config(baseUrl)
})
```

---

**I need to test different systems with different URLs in a single test suite**

This suggests you want to run the test against all urls in the one run.

If so you can iterate an array of urls

```js
const urls = [
  'http://admin-dev.com', 
  'http://admin-qa.com',
  'http://client-dev.com', 
  'http://client-qa.com'
]

urls.forEach(url => {

  describe(`Testing ${url}`, () => {

    before(() => Cypress.config('baseUrl', url))

    it('tests that thing', ...
```

---

If any tests are specific to one environment, i.e must always have client-dev configuration, you can apply the baseUrl at test level

```js
it('tests the other thing', { baseUrl: 'http://client-dev.com' }, () => {
  ...
})
```